# ERROR in Errors parsing template: in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have following code segments in my Test Module `test.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `<h2>Welcome {{name}}</h2><input type="text" value="Taylor"`,
  styles:[

  ]

})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  public name = "Taylor";
  public myId = "testId";


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

but compilar occurred following error message

```
WARNING in AngularCompilerPlugin: Forked Type Checker exited unexpectedly. Falling back to type checking on main thread.

ERROR in Errors parsing template: Unexpected character "EOF" ("nt({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `<h2>Welcome {{name}}</h2><input type="text" value="Taylor"[ERROR ->
]`,
  styles:[

"): D:/Angular/hello-world/src/app/test/test.component.ts@4:71
```

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: did it worked??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you forget to close input tag.
Do it like this, you missed this `>`.

```
template: `<h2>Welcome {{name}}</h2><input type="text" value="Taylor">`
```

Comment: Happy coding.. :)